# Passing a function as a callback to a React state created with hooks did not reflect new value of variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i encounter something very weird here regarding ReactJS state when we store a function on it.

I created a react state with hooks where it contains :

1. number variable
2. callback function

since hooks itself doesn't have callback during setState, i am using this method to toggle the callback during the useEffect once the state is change.

The callback that i pass during the setState is to print out the value of state.number and secondNumber value. after the setState is finished the value of the state.number should be 4, and secondNumber should be 15 (tested if i were to console.log it at the start of the useEffect).

but the state.callback() which will trigger the callback function still print out the original number which is state.number = 2 and secondNumber = 10.

i find it weird since the callback is called after the value of state.number, and secondNumber is change.

Does anybody have an idea on what happen with the code here?

```
    function App(){
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        number : 2,
        callback : null
      });
      let secondNumber = 10;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (state.callback){
          secondNumber = 15;
          state.callback();
        }
      }, [state]);
    
      const toggleButton1 = () => {
       setState({
         number : 4,
         callback : () => {
           console.log('state number',state.number);
           console.log('second number', secondNumber);
         }
       })
      }
      
      return (
        //button trigger function toggleButton1
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

```
const toggleButton1 = () => {
  setState({
    number : 4,
    callback : () => {
      console.log('state number', state.number);
      console.log('second number', secondNumber);
    }
  })
}
```

This encloses the *current* state and `secondNumber` values from the *current* render cycle in the stored callback. Invoking it later will use the value when stored.

## Solution

Simply do in the effect hook what you want to do with the updated state. Functional component state updates don't really have an equivalent of the class-based component's `setState` callback parameter, the `useEffect` with appropriate dependency is its equivalent.

```
function App(){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    number : 2,
    callback : null
  });
  let secondNumber = 10;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state number', state.number);
    console.log('second number', secondNumber);
  }, [state.number]);

  const toggleButton1 = () => {
   setState({
     number : 4,
   })
  }
  
  return (
    //button trigger function toggleButton1
  )
}

export default App;
```

FYI, as defined, `secondNumber` will be reset/redefined back to `10` each render cycle, you can mutate it *within* each cycle but it'll be reset each time.

Comment: Based on your answer i have make some improvement which is on the callback to store the logic of the function only and as for the data need to be retrieve from the callback parameter directly. 

In my scenario i can't just put the logic directly to the useEffect due to the logic that require to run is differ depends on whom trigger the setState itself.

By passing the latest state to the callback
"state.callback(state)"
and only using the variable that passed to the callback inside the logic i was able to achieve what i need. Thanks a lot Drew Reese